# NSOutlineView's outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) get called twice some times

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have an `NSOutlineView` bound to an `NSTreeController`. In the outlineView's delegate, I found that the method `outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)` got called twice when (1) there was a row selected and (2) clicked the title row to collase the group.

The selected rows are both -1. [The doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsoutlineviewdelegate/1526913-outlineviewselectiondidchange) of this method doesn't mention this behaviour.

Is there a way to save one of the two calls?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register for the notification in your delegate?

I observed the same thing you report (`outlineViewSelectionDidChange` was being called twice) and it was due to adding an observer for `NSOutlineViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` in my delegate's `viewDidLoad`. I removed the registration and `outlineViewSelectionDidChange` was called only once.